# what is the difference between sigma field and field? example in probability class

Tags: probability

In probability class, I got an example of  $\sigma$-field and field. But I cannot understand how this example explain about that.

First, assume

$$\mathcal{F} = \{A\subset N\ |\ A\ is\ finite\ or\ A^\mathsf{c}\ is\ finite \} $$

Let $A_i=\{2i\}$, and I understand $A_i ∈\mathcal{F}$. Because $A_i$ is finite. And I also understand $\mathcal{F}$ cannot be a $\sigma$-field in this even number example.

Because

$$\ A_i∈\mathcal{F},\ \forall\ i$$
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\not\in\mathcal{F}$$

But professor said that this $\mathcal{F}$ is the example of a field but not a $\sigma$-field. I'm not sure according to these reasons.

First, if A is in $\mathcal{F}$, there is no assumption $A^\mathsf{c}$ is contained in $\mathcal{F}$. The meaning of $A\subset N$ in definition of $\mathcal{F}$ is 'among all subset of $N$, which satisfy condition after the bar?'

Second, field needs being closed in respect of finite union. How I can certain $\mathcal{F}$ have finite union without assumption to $finite\ N$?

Third, Is $\mathcal{F}$ satisfy the third property of field? (If $A$ and $B$ are in $\mathcal{F}$, $A\cup B$ is also the subset of $\mathcal{F}$.)

Comment: I think you are doing much confusion between $\in$ and $\subset$. For example, you have $A_i \in \mathcal{F}$, not  $A_i \subset \mathcal{F}$. I say this because ambiguity makes your questions harder to be understood. Moreover, i think that all your doubts arise from this confusion.

Comment: I fixed as you comment, but still cannot understand...

Answer (score 1):

Let $A\in \mathcal F$. So by the definition of $\mathcal F$, $A$ is finite or $A^c%$ is finite. If $A$ be finite, then: $A=(A^c)^c$ So, $A^c \in \mathcal F$. If $A$ be infinite, then $A^c$ should be finite. So, $A^c \in \mathcal F$.

Now let $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n \subset \mathcal F$. We should show that: $$\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i \in \mathcal F$$ or $$(\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i)^c=\bigcap_{i=1}^nA_i^c \in \mathcal F$$ If $A_i$ be finite for $i=1,2,...,n$, then $\cup_{i=1}^nA_i$ is finite. else, at lest one of $A_i$ for example $A_{i_0}$ should be infinite. in this case, $A_{i_0}^c$ is finite. Thus $\cap_{i=1}^nA_i^c$ is finite.

Comment: Can I say that if $A_{i_0}$ is infinite, $A_{i_0}^c$ is finite? A complement of infinite even number is also infinite odd number.

Comment: because of $A_{i_0}\in \mathcal F$, if $A_{i_0}$ be infinite, by the definition of $\mathcal F$, we should have "$A_{i_0}^c$ is a finite set".